# log4net:ERROR Appender named [SocketAppender] not found

Tags: c#, log4net

I am getting below error while running a unit test:

```
log4net:ERROR Could not create Appender [SocketAppender] of type [log4net.Appender.SocketAppender, Log4netSocketAppender]. Reported error follows.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Log4netSocketAppender' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Log4netSocketAppender'
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(Assembly relativeAssembly, String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseAppender(XmlElement appenderElement)
```

Can anyone help please ?

Comment: Is the `SocketAppender` library included in your app?

Comment: Yes it is included.